# Multiple links to the same webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to make a script which will have generate random links to the same page. I know I can use a random generator for random alphanumeric string but how can I implement that and redirect it to the same page.

For example:

- `www.domain.com/12345`
- `www.domain.com/23412`
- `www.domain.com/86756`

All these links should be redirected when clicked to the same page, `www.domain.com`. How can I do that?

Comment: If you are using Apache as the webserver, you should be using mod_rewrite to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really depends on how you envision your urls. One simple way could be

```
http://www.domain.com/page/1234
http://www.domain.com/page/5432
```

If you are ok with that url structure, then you can do a [htaccess rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to point all requests containing /page/ to the same place.

It would be something on these lines

```
RewriteRule ^/page/(.*)$ common.php
```

The idea is to have something in the url that is common across all the urls, in this case its 'page'

Comment: Thanks Sabeen. I think I understood how to do that.:)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use rand() or mt_rand() to generate a random integer and append it to your url.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect ALL random number pages to the same page you can simply use .htaccess to track the URL with some pattern (using regular expressions) and redirect them straight to some page.

If you want to track the number you can use .htaccess to rewrite the URL to

```
http://www.domain.com/page.php?id=23412
http://www.domain.com/page.php?id=86756
```

Then you can use $_GET['id'] to get the numbers and do something with them. When the processing is done the following function can be used to redirect the user to a URL of your preference:

```
header('Location:http://www.domain.com');
```

Apache Guide to URL rewriting:
[URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)